# Two versions of mono one accepting certificates other not?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, certificate

I have two machines, each running a differant version of mono:

Machine 1: Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.5 (Debian 2.10.5-1ubuntu0.1)
Machine 2: Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)

I'm deciding to allow all certificates by using `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Validator;`, where `Validator` is:

```
public bool Validator (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,     SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

Machine 1 runs fine and accept certifcates

Machine 2 however is throwing up a big error, i think it might be a certifcates problem

any ideas?

Big error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: Error getting response
stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: EndRead
failure ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by
peer   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (IAsyncResult result)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (IAsyncResult ar) [0x00000]
in <filename unknown>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (IAsyncResult ar)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.InternalReadCallback
(IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    --- End of
inner exception stack trace ---   at
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0    at CRMOnlineSOAPRequests.CRMHelper.GetSOAPResponse
(System.String url, System.String soapEnvelope) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0    at CRMOnlineSOAPRequests.CRMHelper.createEntity
(System.String[] keyValuesOneDimensionalArray) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0    at CRMCreateEntity.Program.Main (System.String[]
keyValuesOneDimensionalArray) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.WebException: Error
getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure --->
System.IO.IOException: EndRead failure --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer   at
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000]
in <filename unknown>:0    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead
(IAsyncResult ar) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    --- End of
inner exception stack trace ---   at
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (IAsyncResult ar) [0x00000]
in <filename unknown>:0    at
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.InternalReadCallback
(IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    --- End of
inner exception stack trace ---   at
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0    at CRMOnlineSOAPRequests.CRMHelper.GetSOAPResponse
(System.String url, System.String soapEnvelope) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0    at CRMOnlineSOAPRequests.CRMHelper.createEntity
(System.String[] keyValuesOneDimensionalArray) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0    at CRMCreateEntity.Program.Main (System.String[]
keyValuesOneDimensionalArray) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: I have subsequently tried compiling the code using machine 2 and run it (even though in my head c# is a virtual machine) but it has made no differance

Comment: Having the same issue. It will work some times but the other times I keep getting this exception. Very Annoying